# Is it possible to add inline C# objects to a theory in xUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have some custom C# objects which I want to pass as `InlineData` arguments in xUnit's `Theory`.

I tried [the answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36429716/9164071) without any success since my objects are not strings and therefore cannot be created as compile time constants (*An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type*).

Here is what I tried,

```
private static readonly Card sevenOfHearts = Card.SevenOfHearts;
private static readonly Card sevenOfSpades = Card.SevenOfSpades;
private static readonly Card sevenOfDiamonds = Card.SevenOfDiamonds;
private static readonly Card sevenOfClubs = Card.SevenOfClubs;

[Theory]
[InlineData(sevenOfHearts)]
[InlineData(sevenOfSpades)]
[InlineData(sevenOfDiamonds)]
[InlineData(sevenOfClubs)]
void Test(
  Card card)
{
  //...
}
```

but I am getting complains that those objects **are not compile time constants**.

Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Is that the exact text of the error?  You should post error messages verbatim when possible.

Comment: You can achieve this using ClassData instead of InlineData (a nice example can be found here https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/) or with MemberData

Comment: Allright I'll post the exact text of the error @Wyck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `MemberData` attribute for that. It should return `IEnumerable<object[]>`, where every item represents a set of parameters for your test method (in your case only one `Card` parameter, so only one item)

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object[]> Cards
{
    get
    {
        yield return new object[] { Card.SevenOfHearts };
        yield return new object[] { Card.SevenOfSpades };
        yield return new object[] { Card.SevenOfDiamonds };
        yield return new object[] { Card.SevenOfClubs };
    }
}

[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(Cards))]
void Test(Card card)   
{    
}
```

Comment: Btw the `IEnumerable` also needs to be public.